# TabHost not loading properly?

Tags: java, android, android-tabhost

I am having a problem with my TabHost activity not loading correctly due to an error. Here's my code, xml, and error logs:

```
public class TabScreen extends TabActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab_screen);

    TabHost t = getTabHost();
    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);


    //For New Photos
    TabSpec newSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("NewPhoto");
    newSpec.setIndicator("NewPhoto", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_newphoto));
    Intent phNewIntent = new Intent(this, NewPhoto.class);
    newSpec.setContent(phNewIntent);
    //For List of Taken Photos
    TabSpec listSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("PhotoList");
    listSpec.setIndicator("PhotoList", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_photolist));
    Intent phListIntent = new Intent(this, PhotoList.class);
    listSpec.setContent(phListIntent);
    //For Map
    TabSpec mapSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("PhotoMap");
    mapSpec.setIndicator("PhotoMap", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_photomap));
    Intent phMapIntent = new Intent(this, PhotoMap.class);
    mapSpec.setContent(phMapIntent);

    tabHost.addTab(newSpec);
    tabHost.addTab(listSpec);
    tabHost.addTab(mapSpec);
}


}
```

And my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and finally, my error messages:(There was a long list, but the main one I believe to be the problem is what I'm pasting)

```
12-02 16:00:06.250: E/AndroidRuntime(3757): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-02 16:00:06.250: E/AndroidRuntime(3757): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start         activity ComponentInfo{edu.wcu.snipsnaps/edu.wcu.snipsnaps.TabScreen}:     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity     ComponentInfo{edu.wcu.snipsnaps/edu.wcu.snipsnaps.NewPhoto}: java.lang.RuntimeException:     Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'
```

There are multiple entries on this website about this problem, but after looking at every one, none of the solutions worked. My xml has the proper @android:id/tabhost, and I deleted my R.java file and cleaned the entire project numerous times. If this helps, when I was doing some debugging, the place where the application fell apart was at the `tabHost.addTab(newSpec);` . Anyone know what's going on?

EDIT: Full error log:

```
12-02 17:02:43.296: E/AndroidRuntime(8121): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{edu.wcu.snipsnaps/edu.wcu.snipsnaps.TabScreen}:     java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is     'android.R.id.tabhost'
12-02 17:02:43.296: E/AndroidRuntime(8121):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
12-02 17:02:43.296: E/AndroidRuntime(8121):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
12-02 17:02:43.296: E/AndroidRuntime(8121):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-02 17:02:43.296: E/AndroidRuntime(8121):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
12-02 17:02:43.296: E/AndroidRuntime(8121):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-02 17:02:43.296: E/AndroidRuntime(8121):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-02 17:02:43.296: E/AndroidRuntime(8121):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
12-02 17:02:43.296: E/AndroidRuntime(8121):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-02 17:02:43.296: E/AndroidRuntime(8121):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-02 17:02:43.296: E/AndroidRuntime(8121):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
12-02 17:02:43.296: E/AndroidRuntime(8121):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
12-02 17:02:43.296: E/AndroidRuntime(8121):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-02 17:02:43.296: E/AndroidRuntime(8121): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'
12-02 17:02:43.296: E/AndroidRuntime(8121):     at android.app.TabActivity.onContentChanged(TabActivity.java:105)
12-02 17:02:43.296: E/AndroidRuntime(8121):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:212)
12-02 17:02:43.296: E/AndroidRuntime(8121):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
12-02 17:02:43.296: E/AndroidRuntime(8121):     at edu.wcu.snipsnaps.TabScreen.onCreate(TabScreen.java:16)
12-02 17:02:43.296: E/AndroidRuntime(8121):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-02 17:02:43.296: E/AndroidRuntime(8121):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
12-02 17:02:43.296: E/AndroidRuntime(8121):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in code

```
TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
```

Instead of :

```
TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
```

In XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

Instead of

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

Also 
May be you need to change all ids in views from android:id="@android:id...." to like android:id="@+id/....." , @android is reserved for androids default elements

Link for help http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/

Comment: May be you need to change all ids in views from android:id="@android:id to like android:id="@+id/ , @android is reserved for androids default elements.

Comment: New Link added in answer at end for more help. [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/)

Comment: I don't understand what's going on... according to this link you gave me, my code is pretty much that guy's code, and it's still not working.

Comment: have you changed in XML android:id="@android:id...." to like android:id="@+id/....."  and then in code need to change android.R.id. to R.id.

Comment: Yes sir, I changed it to @+id and I changed the code to = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost);

Comment: Try using 

TabHost tabHost  = getTabHost();

Comment: No dice :( I added a full error log in the post, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - -

I wasn't properly extending TabActivity in all of my classes to be displayed in the tab.

Thanks for the help!!